# CSS square constraint by parent height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page layout made of :

- a fixed height header : HEADER
- a fixed height footer : FOOTER
- a flex grow content to fill the available remaining height : CONTENT

I would like the flex grow content to hold a square div whose dimensions are equals to the **height** of the CONTENT element.

I cannot achieve this constraint because using width = 100vh for the square does not compute 100% of the CONTENT height !!!

You can check here what I have so far : http://jsfiddle.net/tgs93kLr/

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.body {
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: red;
}
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
.square {
  background: black;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this
NB : I already have a solution for the case where CONTENT width < height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `calc` and set height and width to `100vh - (header height + footer height)`

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: red;
}
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
.square {
  background: black;
  width: calc(100vh - 200px);
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set height on body then you are going to use that height instead of `100vh` http://jsfiddle.net/tgs93kLr/1/

Comment: great it works fine... Is there a similar solution for non fixed height header ?